# What changed between python 2.7 and 3.x to affect this "snap to grid" code?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, math, grid

For a long time now I've used this little "algorithim" to snap things to a grid in python 2.7:

`mouse_x,mouse_y=31,45
 mse=[mouse_x,mouse_y]
 mse_snap=(((mse[0])/32)*32,((mse[1])/32)*32)
 print(mse_snap)`

and it would output: `[0,32]`

essentially snapping it to the closest position on a 32x32 grid (or whatever size I wanted).

BUT! Now, I've upgraded to Python 3.6 and the *exact* same code outputs: `[31.0,45.0]`

I don't really know whats going on here, or where to begin researching to find out. Can anyone offer some intel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2 integer division also floors the result, while Python 3 will return a floating point number.

**Python 2.7:**

```
>>> 31/32
0
```

**Python 3.5:**

```
>>> 31/32
0.96875
```

You can make it behave as expected by replacing the last line with

```
 mse_snap=(int((mse[0])/32)*32, int((mse[1])/32)*32)
```

---

**Edit:** This is identical as long as the values are positive. Converting to an `int` rounds towards zero, which is identical to floor only with positive numbers. If you expect negative values, use `math.floor` instead:

```
from math import floor

...

mse_snap=(floor((mse[0])/32)*32, floor((mse[1])/32)*32)
```

Comment: Ok sweet! Works outstandingly.

Comment: In hindsight I probably should have been able to figure that out by looking at the output, but thank you for your help! Still getting used to using parenthesis on `print` as well, haha.

Comment: No problem! There's an important bit that I forgot to add in my post. I edited it in, so if negative coordinates are a possibility you should take a look at the edit.